# Не могу загрузить картинки через Webpack 5 после перехода с 4 Подскажите

Tags: reactjs, изображения, webpack, jsx

сам конфиг и зависимости
ошибка просто 404, подключаю картинки в jsx через src раньше все работало
src="../../../../../img/logo_white.webp"

```
   "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.5",
    "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.79.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3",
    "yargs": "^13.3.2"

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const isProd = argv.mode === "production";
  const config = {
    entry: "./src/index.jsx",
    output: {
      publicPath: "auto",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /.jsx?$/,
          use: ["babel-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /.s?css$/,
          use: [
            isProd ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader",
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$/i,
          type: "asset/resource",
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
  };

  if (isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
      })
    );
  }

  return config;
};
```